# Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error; error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, heroku

So far everything as far as my git/heroku experience has been perfect.

Most recently I tried to push a new commit, and got the following "unrecognized error":

```
-bash> git push heroku master 
Counting objects: 29, done. 
Delta compression using up to 2 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 1.78 KiB, done. 
Total 18 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push 
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected 
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets 
Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done 
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile 
Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done 
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout 
Installing rails_log_stdout... done 
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7 
All dependencies are satisfied 
-----> Compiled slug size is 14.5MB 
-----> Launching... 
! Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error. 
! We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.

To git@heroku.com:thing-thing-1234.git 
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:thing-thing-1234.git'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! Problem solved. Shortly after I did `git status` and saw that I had not actually added the files. So the above was an attempt to push an empty commit. Here's what I had done:

```
-bash> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile 
-bash> git commit -m "vendor compiled assets" 
-bash> git push heroku master
```

But I should have done this:

```
-bash> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile 
-bash> git add .
-bash> git commit -m "vendor compiled assets" 
-bash> git push heroku master
```